# Pytorch lightning callback for switching dataloader_idx

Tags: pytorch-lightning, wandb

Is there a callback or something similar used when incrementing the dataloader index? The reason is that I have defined multiple dataloaders and I would like to start a new run with weight and biases for each dataloader.

Answer (score 0):

Engineer from W&B here.

One thing you could do is update the dataset in the setup callback of your datamodule.

However, could you please share a snippet of your code. I don't think I entirely understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: The `setup` call in my datamodule is only being called once in the start of the run. The datamodule returns a list of dataloaders in the `test_dataloader` method, each dataloader is associated with some particular configuration and I am trying to capture this configuration somehow in wandb. I posted something similar a while back in the wandb community: https://community.wandb.ai/t/grouping-custom-metrics-by-configuration/1995